# How do I mock an external dependency in Rust

Tags: testing, rust, mocking

I have a method which calls the external dependency `walkdir::WalkDir`, and would like to test that I'm handling its output correctly. Ideally by mocking the response of the dependency.

My code looks like this:

```rust
use walkdir::{IntoIter,WalkDir};

pub struct MyStruct<'a> {
    pub path: &'a Path
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn _walk_wrapper(&self) -> IntoIter {
        WalkDir::new(self.path)
            .into_iter()
    }

    pub fn foo(&self) -> Vec<&str> {
        let walk = self._walk_wrapper();

        // do something with the walk results
        // return a vector of values
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Maybe what you need is to invert this, instead wrap WalkDir *all the time* in a `trait` you control, like `trait Walkable`. Then you can wrap your mock in the same trait as well. Never use `WalkDir` directly, instead invoke it via your trait. An alternative is an enum like `enum Walkable { Dir(WalkDir), List(Vec<PathBuf>) }` which could simplify design, but limits extensibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3 approaches:

1. Just conditionally implement this method differently.

```rust
use walkdir::{IntoIter,WalkDir};

pub struct MyStruct<'a> {
    pub path: &'a Path
}

impl MyStruct {
    #[cfg(not(test))]
    fn _walk_wrapper(&self) -> impl IntoIter {
        WalkDir::new(self.path)
            .into_iter()
    }

    #[cfg(test)]
    fn _walk_wrapper(&self) -> impl IntoIter {
        ["x.txt", "my_cat.jps"].into_iter()
    }

    pub fn foo(&self) -> Vec<&str> {
        let walk = self._walk_wrapper();

        // do something with the walk results
        // return a vector of values
    }
}
```

This approach has big downsides, for example, all your tests would get same output.
And you wouldn't be able test real behaviour in future.

You may try to use [`mockall`](https://docs.rs/mockall/latest/mockall/) for mocking tests.

2. Use generics and traits:

```rust
use walkdir::{IntoIter,WalkDir};

trait WalkDirImpl {
   type It: Iterator;
   fn get_values(path: &Path)->Self::It;
}

impl WalkDirImpl for WalkDir {
   type It: ...;
   fn get_values() -> Self::It{
        WalkDir::new(self.path)
            .into_iter()
    }
}

pub struct MyStruct<'a> {
    pub path: &'a Path
}

impl MyStruct {
    #[cfg(not(test))]
    fn _walk_wrapper(&self) -> impl IntoIter {
        WalkDir::new(self.path)
            .into_iter()
    }

    #[cfg(test)]
    fn _walk_wrapper(&self) -> impl IntoIter {
        ["x.txt", "my_cat.jps"].into_iter()
    }

    pub fn foo<WalkWrapper=WalkDir>(&self) -> Vec<&str>
       where WalkWrapper: WalkDirImpl
    {
        let walk = self._walk_wrapper();

        // do something with the walk results
        // return a vector of values
    }
}
#[test]
fn my_test() {
    struct TestProvider;
    impl WalkDirImpl for TestProvider{
       type It: ...;
       fn get_values() -> Self::It{
          ["x.txt", "my_cat.jps"].into_iter()
       }
    }
    
    MyStruct::foo::<TestProvider>
}
```

This approach has downsides too. For example, you start to leak foreign type from your public interface.
To prevent this, you can wrap your generic struct/methdod into some public struct/method and use inner private generic struct/method.

3. This is variation of first approach.

```
type OverrideFun = fn()->Vec<PathBuf>;
// Use thread local to store override function.
// Thread local because tests runs in parallel.
#[cfg(test)]
thread_local!{
   static OVERRIDE_FUN_PTR: Cell<Option<OverrideFun>> = Cell::new(None);
};

fn get_children(path:&Path)->Vec<PathBuf>{
   // If test, try to load override.
   #[cfg(test)]
   {
      let mut res = None;
      OVERRIDE_FUN_PTR.with(|cell|{
         let fun = cell.get();
         res = fun();
      });
      if let Some(res) = res{
         return res;
      }
   }


   WalkDir::new(path)
            .into_iter()
            .collect()
}

#[test]
fn my_test(){
   OVERRIDE_FUN_PTR.with(|cell|{
         cell.set(||vec!["x.txt", "my_cat.jpg"]);
   });
   assert_eq!(get_children(""), vec!["x.txt", "my_cat.jpg"]);
}
```

This version is good because it is configurable. Because `#[cfg(test)]` it only affects tests and wouldn't be compiled into your result binary.
And you could store anything in that threadlocal, really.